# Manipulating 2 lists to generate a GeoGraphics Plot

Tags: plotting, geographics

I have 2 lists for location and Radius that I would like to run with `GeoGraphics`.

```
llist = {{-34.6077, -58.692}, {-23.5727, -46.65}, {6.3155, -75.9408},
{-16.6438, -70.451}, {-2.0426, -60.092}, {-53.092, -72.04}}

R = {Quantity[100, "Kilometers"], Quantity[200, "Kilometers"], 
Quantity[300, "Kilometers"], Quantity[400, "Kilometers"], 
Quantity[500, "Kilometers"], Quantity[600, "Kilometers"]}
```

When making a plot I have:

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[Directive[Opacity[0.2], EdgeForm[Blue], Red]], 
 GeoDisk[llist[[1]], #1] & /@ R}, 
 GeoRange -> {{-60, 15}, {-100, -15}}, GeoProjection -> "Mollweide", 
 GeoGridLines -> Quantity[5, "AngularDegrees"], 
 GeoBackground -> "ContourMap"]
```

or

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[
 Directive[Opacity[0.2], EdgeForm[Blue], Red]], 
 GeoDisk[#, R[[1]]] & /@ llist}, 
 GeoRange -> {{-60, 15}, {-100, -15}}, GeoProjection -> "Mollweide", 
 GeoGridLines -> Quantity[5, "AngularDegrees"], 
 GeoBackground -> "ContourMap"]
```

[image: Outuput]

or

[image: Alternate Output]

What I want is something like this:

[image]

I believe the whole problem is how to deal with the 2 lists above when using the `GeoDisk` command. However I might be in the wrong direction and perhaps could use an alternative approach.

Sorry if this is a double post but I tried to see similar approachs with no success.

Comment: Try `MapThread[GeoDisk, {llist, R}]`.

Comment: It DID work !!! Thanks a Million.

Answer (score 1):

```
llist = {{-34.6077, -58.692}, {-23.5727, -46.65},
   {6.3155, -75.9408}, {-16.6438, -70.451},
   {-2.0426, -60.092}, {-53.092, -72.04}};

R = {Quantity[100, "Kilometers"], Quantity[200, "Kilometers"],
   Quantity[300, "Kilometers"], Quantity[400, "Kilometers"],
   Quantity[500, "Kilometers"], Quantity[600, "Kilometers"]};
```

**EDIT:** Added intensity data and changed projection

```
intensity = 3 QuantityMagnitude[R]/200.; (* substitute your actual intensity data *)
```

Group each location with its associated radius and intensity.

```
data = Transpose[{llist, R, intensity}];

GeoGraphics[{
    GeoStyling[
     Opacity[0.5],
     EdgeForm[Blue],
     ColorData["Rainbow"][
      Rescale[#[[3]], MinMax[intensity]]]],
    GeoDisk @@ (Most@#)} & /@ data,
 GeoRange -> {{-60, 15}, {-100, -15}},
 GeoProjection -> "AzimuthalEquidistant",
 GeoGridLines -> Quantity[5, "AngularDegrees"],
 GeoBackground -> "ContourMap"]
```

[image]

Comment: I got this as well and perhaps should either use another approach or correct this distortion.

Comment: Besides I have to figure out how to color the disks proportional to their "intensities"...